# Mongodb match with multiple condition not working

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have `user` collection having data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "password" : "******",
    "activation" : "Active",
    "userType" : "Author",
    "email" : "something@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Something",
    "profilePicture" : "profile_pictures/5da594c15324fec81d0000271607094354423image.png",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

On the other hand `userlog` has data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb7bb4485c34a41900002b"),
    "duration" : 2.54,
    "page" : 1,
    "activityDetails" : "Viewed Page for seconds",
    "contentType" : "article",
    "activityType" : "articlePageStayTime",
    "bookId" : ObjectId("5f93e2cc74153f8c1800003f"),
    "ipAddress" : "::1",
    "creator" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "created" : ISODate("2020-12-05T12:23:16.867Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I need is data like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "password" : "******",
    "activation" : "Active",
    "userType" : "Author",
    "email" : "something@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Something",
    "profilePicture" : "profile_pictures/5da594c15324fec81d0000271607094354423image.png",
    "userlogs":
    [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb7bb4485c34a41900002b"),
    "duration" : 2.54,
    "page" : 1,
    "activityDetails" : "Viewed Page for seconds",
    "contentType" : "article",
    "activityType" : "articlePageStayTime",
    "bookId" : ObjectId("5f93e2cc74153f8c1800003f"),
    "ipAddress" : "::1",
    "creator" : ObjectId("5da594c15324fec81d000027"),
    "created" : ISODate("2020-12-05T12:23:16.867Z"),
    "__v" : 0
    }]
```

}

I am trying to find all the user except admin with their log for each month. So my condition is user wont be admin and date will be between two range. But it is not working. My current code is below which is returning empty dataset-

```
User
    .aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userType: {
                $ne:"admin"
            }           

        },
        "$and": [
                {
                    "userlogs.created": {
                        $lte: dateCompare.end
                    }
                },
                {
                    "userlogs.created": {
                        $gte: dateCompare.start
                    }
                }

            ]   
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "userlogs", //or Races.collection.name
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "creator",
            as: "userlogs"
        },
        
    },
    

    ]
```

I am using **mongodb version 3.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userType: {
                $ne:"admin"
            }           

        },
    {
        $graphLookup:{
            from: "userlogs", //or Races.collection.name
            startWith: "$_id",
            connectToField:"creator",
            connectFromField:"_id", 
            maxDepth:0,
            as: "userlogs",
            restrictSearchWithMatch:{created:{
                 $lte:dateCompare.end,
                 $gte:dateCompare.start
                  }} 

        },
        
    }   ]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is returning the dataset. But  the date range is not working. All data are returning.

Comment: Thanks. It is  working now. Unwind is just creating instances for each userlogs element. But why would that fix the date range problem? Care to explain?

Comment: I wrote something quicker for you anyways. Check it now @HassanNomani. You'll get an array of documents with desired conditions.